# How to prevent nextDNS VPN profile from being deleted on reboot on macOS 10.15 Catalina

Tags: vpn, catalina, configuration-profiles

I use nextDNS from the Mac App Store to manage all my DNS queries. The program is set to launch at login and when it first launches the following dialog window opens:

[image: NextDNS Add VPN Configuration]

Selecting 'Allow' stores a VPN profile under System Preferences > Network.

[image: NextDNS VPN Profile]

The problem is that the VPN profile gets deleted on each reboot and the dialog window thus re-appears.

Any ideas as to why the VPN profile gets deleted? Is there a way to prevent the VPN profile from being deleted?